# Heroku Deployments have changed since September 2017

Tags: git, maven, heroku

When I am deploying my java web application to heroku, I am currently having to mandatorily include the pom.xml for even web applications which do not essentially require any dependency management. Now I believe this is primarily to include the Web App runner jar which helps perform a push to a private repo that has been created while creating the APP.
[image]
Now if I can remember correctly Heroku allowed customers to deploy code back in September, which did not require pom.xml for dynamic web projects.
Has anything changed since then?
Also is the git repo where the code is being pushed private?